# ParseUser with an array of pointers unpins the CurrentUser?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I need to fetch a ParseUser and each ParseUser object has an Array of Pointers to other ParseUsers (for example: each user has a list of followers and a list of users he/she is following)

So I do my fetch pretty normal and get my list of users

```java
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.include("following");
query.include("followers");
query.getInBackground(objectId,localCoiffeurItemCallback);
```

But when I add a pointer, and close the app. I lose the session

```java
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.add("firstName",newParseUser);
user.saveInBackGround();
```

The user will update correctly! But, when I restart the app, it does not find the current user and asks for login !

I spent the day tracking this down, and it came to this:
If I include a List of ParseUser, I lose my CurrentUser!

**EDIT**
I have created a GitHub repo with a simple exmaple of this problem.
https://github.com/alaouiali/TestParseUser/tree/master

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A possible work around is that you should be able to save a session token from the ParseUser then use that to log back in after the issue/bug occurs.  I'm not sure if this is a bug with the SDK or something you are doing wrong. We just use automatic users so getCurrentUser is never null.

Comment: @DaveS I really want this to work without any workaround. So, I created a github repo with JUST 2 acitivities with the code that does not work. Because I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see any red flags that jump out at me. I'd make sure your parse keys aren't actually in the repo (I didn't check if it was set in your resources) and ask the Parse guys on their Q&A site.